# Cloudfront RTMP stream with signed URL not instantly viewable

Tags: amazon-web-services, stream, amazon-cloudfront, rtmp, signed

We have had a cloudfront rtmp streaming service set up, which seems to work. Upon requesting a streaming url, we get a signed url, with which I've been able to view the stream in JWPlayer and the Wowza Testplayer - after waiting for 20-50 seconds.

Before that, the wowza testplayer says "Failed to play (stream ID: 1)" and JWPlayer says "Error loading stream: ID not found on server".
After waiting some seconds (usually something around 20-50 seconds), the stream can be viewed.

The Amazon services were set up for us and I wasn't able to reach these people yet. I haven't found any other cases describing this problem and I would be happy for any pointers on where the problem could be (or what exactly the problem is).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the problem was that the server generating the signed urls and the streaming server had a slight time difference of ~40 seconds, which resulted in urls valid in +40 seconds on the streaming server.
Including time synchronisation between the servers fixed this.